# htaccess: rewrite path AND querystring to querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like do the following mod_rewrite via htaccess:

```
/xxx/yyy/?zzz=2  -->  /index.php?src=xxx/yyy/&zzz=2
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't work (404 error):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?src=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [P,L]
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P` flag is not used for what you want to do.
You have to use `QSA` flag instead (**Q**uery **S**tring **A**ppend)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?src=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, make sure *mod_rewrite* is **enabled** in your Apache server config (and **AllowOverride** has the right value to enable htaccess, for example **All** instead of **None**)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to validate my answer to solve your question